# Converting a javascript function to pass in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript which is working great -

```
var employeename = $("#employeename");
var employeenameInfo = $("#employeenameInfo");
employeename.blur(validateEmployeename);

function validateEmployeename(){
    //if it's NOT valid
    if(employeename.val().length < 4){
        employeename.addClass("error");
        employeenameInfo.text("We want names with more than 3 letters!");
        employeenameInfo.addClass("error");
        return false;
    }
    //if it's valid
    else{
        employeename.removeClass("error");
        employeenameInfo.text("Full Name.");
        employeenameInfo.removeClass("error");
        return true;
    }
}
```

However instead of having a big list of this functions for all my different fields I want to pass a field in e.g.

```
function validateGeneric(field){
```

However whatever I try just gives me errors and I'm really stuck. Any help appreciated. This also brings up another problem with the info field, any way I can store the orginal text and just restore that instead of a new string?

Comment: So could you show the code that isn't working? It's hard to fix code that you can't see...

Comment: To restore your "info" fields content, build a dictionary: `var infoDic = { employeenameInfo: "Full Name.", xxx: "xxx", etc. };`. Then use infoDic to retrieve the content of your field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the field that triggered the event using $(this). also you should put the info field as a sibling with an info class

```
$('input.to_be_validated').blur(validateInput);

function validateInput(e){
    var input = $(this)
    var info = input.parent.find('.info')
    //if it's NOT valid
    if(input.val().length < 4){
        input.addClass("error");
        info.text("We want names with more than 3 letters!");
        info.addClass("error");
        return false;
    }
    //if it's valid
    else{
        input.removeClass("error");
        info.text("Full Name.");
        info.removeClass("error");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Edit: forgot about the info field

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to reference the `field` var you'd pass into your function, therefore your code becomes:

```
function validateEmployeename(field, fieldinfo){
    //if it's NOT valid
    if(field.val().length < 4){
        field.addClass("error");
        fieldinfo.text("We want names with more than 3 letters!");
        fieldinfo.addClass("error");
        return false;
    }
    //if it's valid
    else{
        field.removeClass("error");
        fieldinfo.text("Full Name.");
        fieldinfo.removeClass("error");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use multiple selectors:

```
$("input[name='employeename'], input[name='employeename2']").blur(function() {
    // put your validation routine for fields that should contain names
    $(this).next("#employeenameInfo").html("info here"); // note that you don't have unique id here, better to find element you want to put your error message by tagname/class, like "span.error"
});

$("input[name='employeemail'], input[name='employeemail2']").blur(function() {
    // put your validation routine for fields that should contain email addresses
    $(this).next("#emailInfo").html("info here"); // note that you don't have unique id here, better to find element you want to put your error message by tagname/class, like "span.error" 
});
```

That way you don't need to pass anything to validation functions, everything will be resolved around `$(this)`, providing you've got proper elements to fill your error messages nearby:

```
<input type="text" name="employeename" />
<span class="error" />
```